# How to redirect if form is not submitted

Tags: java, php, html

I have form for registration (for example:`www.register.com`), once the user fills the form and clicks on submit, he will be redirected to another page (for example: `www.thanku.com`).

This is all working fine but how can I redirect to `www.register.com` when a user directly enters (without submission) the `www.thanku.com`?

Comment: Yes they can - if you ask the question properly - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Page thanku.com, first check if user submitted any post request

e.g

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])
 {
   header('Location: http://www.register.com/');
   exit;
 }
```

Comment: on submission i am already redirecting it to another page,now i dont want any one to directly enter that page url and access it

Comment: hard to understand without any code - can you give an example of how you redirecting to another page, and how you are getting data on that page?
Are you submitting any data when redirecting to another page?

Comment: once user submitts the form(submitted data will be sent to email id) , it will redirect to another page which say thank you for submitting.

Comment: So, you want to redirect user if come to thanks for your submitting page, if access it directly by typing URL in browser? Did i understand?

Comment: May i please see the code with redirecting? How you do redirect?

Comment: if(!empty($name)&& !empty($cname)&&!empty($mobileno)&& !empty($email)&&!empty($city)&&!empty($postalcode)&&!empty($address)){
   header('Location: thanku.php');
   exit();}

Comment: Hmm.. you may try to append ?some_var=true to your link like 
 header('Location: thanku.php?from_submit=1');

And then in thanks.php check if $from_submit exists and if not redirect user immediately to another page, if does exists, show content of thanks page

Comment: I am really new to php,can you please elaborate

Comment: @Vladdv i am sorry,i am unable to do it, its ok i ll work on it as you guided,thank you

Comment: sure, ping me with message if its not working for you and i ll try to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Submit button to send any value:

```
<input type="Submit" name="SubmitButton" value="1">
```

And then just check if the variable is set:

```
if( !isset($_POST['SubmitButton']) ) {//button not clicked
    //your redirect code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(!$answer1 && !$answer2 && !$answer3) {
    header('Location: http://www.register.com/');           
    } else {
    // Your code is here    
    }
}
```